# Last line of csv file is not read by fread from package data.table with error message 'Discarded single-line footer'

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have a csv file that has windows line endings (CR LF) and is separated by semicolon. The last line in the file is an empty line, i.e. no semicolons contained or any other character.

When reading the file with `fread` from the `data.table` package the second last line, i.e. the last data row, is not loaded and the error message says "**Discarded single-line footer**".

Comment: Try setting `blank.lines.skip=FALSE`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try inserting `fill = TRUE`.

In my case, inserting `fill = true` all works correctly.